# Npm on Homestead

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-5, homestead

I just made laravel5 environment using homestead.
And I did "npm install", and got the errors below.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/casts$ npm install

> node-sass@3.1.2 install /home/vagrant/Code/casts/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at /home/vagrant/Code/casts/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-11/binding.node

> node-sass@3.1.2 postinstall /home/vagrant/Code/casts/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` /home/vagrant/Code/casts/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-11/binding.node ` exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/home/vagrant/.npm/9fb4c098-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/vagrant/.npm/9fb4c098-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/Code/casts
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/.npm/9fb4c098-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I guess "packages.json" could be okay, but the problem might be caused by npm.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm flooded with errors, i needed things like using `--no-bin-links`, and installing as `sudo` which i "never" want to do ordinarily, and I''m still running into issues, cant get `npm run watch` to work for e.g..  its a real mess.  Im about to throw in the towel as i need to get some production going here.

Answer (score 16):

Had the same issue recently, fixed by updating npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: Just confirming that this solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` did the trick, and I don't have time to figure out why. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try doing `sudo npm install` instead.

If node-sass doesn't work you could always swap this out for something else, I believe they all export a `sass()` method anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need super user privilegies for update npm

**sudo su**

then

**npm i -g npm**